# Sql Syntax to tag rows in a table where this specific criteria appears at least once or more

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, unpivot

I am using SQL Server 2014 and I have a table (t1) which contains a list of 6 numbers in more than 25,000 rows.

Extract of t1 is given below:

```
Id    F1   F2   F3   F4   F5   F6
1     5    11   15   21   30   36
2     8    10   21   25   32   39
3     10   18   23   27   28   32
...
```

I would like to write 2 Case Statements that would do the following:

- (1) tag the rows where the last digit of any of the 6 numbers (F1 to
  F6) appear at least once or more as a "Yes", (else "No")
- (2) give the count of all numbers (based on condition (1) above),
  else give a zero

This is what I am expecting as output:

```
Id    F1   F2   F3   F4   F5   F6  LastDigit   CountLastDigit
1     5    11   15   21   30   36    Yes            4
2     8    10   21   25   32   39    No             0
3     10   18   23   27   28   32    Yes            2
...
```

I am stuck at writing the logic behind the 2 case statements. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you get `4` on `CountLastDigit` on the first row, while only to columns have the same last digit?

Comment: It is because we have 2 pairs of numbers having the same last digits (5 and 15, 11 and 21)

Comment: I speculated on that. But then you should have 4 on the third row as well instead of 2, since there is one pair for last digit 0 and one pair for 8, right?

Comment: Aside: TSQL supports a [`case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) _expression_, but there is no `case` _statement_.

Comment: @GMB yes you are right. I mistyped that one. I have edited my question by changing the last number.

Comment: The phrase "appear at least once" doesn't make sense. Either they _all_ appear at least once or they are `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lateral join seems like the right approach.  I would do an aggregation as part of the effort:

```
select t.*, (case when c.num_duplicates > 0 then 'Yes' else 'No' end) as lastDigit,
       coalesce(c.num_duplicates, 0)
from t cross apply
     (select sum(cnt) as num_duplicates
      from (select f % 10 as digit, count(*) as cnt
            from (values (t.f1), (t.f2), (t.f3), (t.f4), (t.f5), (t.f6)) v(f)
            group by f % 10
            having count(*) > 1
           ) c
     ) c;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4b5a229cc4493ec73dbc4f90bdbb39dd) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

That's an interesting question. You can do this with a lateral join. The idea is to unpivot the number columns to rows, aggregate by the last digit and keep the most occuring only. Then you just need to add a little conditional logic:

```
select *
from mytable t
cross apply (
    select top (1) 
        case when count(*) = 1 then 'No' else 'Yes'    end LastDigit,
        case when count(*) = 1 then 0    else count(*) end CountLastDigit
    from (values(f1), (f2), (f3), (f4), (f5), (f6)) x(f)
    group by f % 10
    order by CountLastDigit desc
) z
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=326d76a8c57617901a417a0dfbf498fe)**:

```
Id | F1 | F2 | F3 | F4 | F5 | F6 | LastDigit | CountLastDigit
-: | -: | -: | -: | -: | -: | -: | :-------- | -------------:
 1 |  5 | 11 | 15 | 21 | 30 | 36 | Yes       |              2
 2 |  8 | 10 | 21 | 25 | 32 | 39 | No        |              0
 3 | 10 | 18 | 23 | 27 | 28 | 30 | Yes       |              2
```

If you want to sum the count of top ties, then one more level of aggregation is needed in the subquery:

```
select *
from mytable t
cross apply (
    select 
        max(LastDigit) LastDigit,
        sum(CountLastDigit) CountLastDigit
    from (
        select top (1) with ties
            case when count(*) = 1 then 'No' else 'Yes'    end LastDigit,
            case when count(*) = 1 then 0    else count(*) end CountLastDigit
        from (values(f1), (f2), (f3), (f4), (f5), (f6)) x(f)
        group by f % 10
        order by CountLastDigit desc
    ) z
) z
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT ID, COL, VAL
    FROM
    (
        SELECT Id, F1%10 F1, F2%10 F2, F3%10 F3, F4%10 F4, F5%10 F5, F6%10 F6
        FROM @TAB
    )T
    UNPIVOT 
    (
        VAL FOR COL IN ( F1, F2, F3, F4, F5, F6 )
    )UPVT
)
, CTE2 AS
(
    SELECT ID, VAL LastDigit, COUNT(DISTINCT COL) VAL_COUNT 
    FROM CTE
    GROUP BY ID, VAL
)
SELECT T.Id, F1, F2, F3, F4, F5, F6
, CASE WHEN VAL_COUNT > 1 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END LastDigit
, CASE WHEN VAL_COUNT > 1 THEN SUM(VAL_COUNT) ELSE 0 END CountLastDigit 
FROM @tab T
LEFT JOIN CTE2 ON T.Id = CTE2.Id AND VAL_COUNT > 1
GROUP BY T.Id, F1, F2, F3, F4, F5, F6, VAL_COUNT
ORDER BY Id
```

Please find the db<>fiddle **[here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7f742a294d4e3ddcde2829ee720b0cd3)**.